# MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT usage in nsis

Tags: nsis

Using MUI2.nsh. The MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT definition is ignored:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Page title"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "Welcome to the installer. \
\
Begin by clicking Install \
Depending on computer you may need to be \
very patient. \
Watch the hard drive light!"

;-------------------------------------
;Pages
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
```

The welcome page displays with "Name Setup" as the page title. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page header is not visible on the Welcome and Finish pages, you need to use `MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE`.

See the "Page settings > Welcome page settings" section in the [MUI readme](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html).